# FFmpeg: Getting this error while trying to add a logo to video (Unable to find a suitable output format for ..)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, ffprobe

Hey guys I want to add a logo to my video with ffmpeg but I am getting this error while running the below command. What is the reason? Please do help.

```
`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01)' overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01): Invalid argument.`
```

I am using python subprocess to run ffmpeg commands.

```
subprocess.call([settings.VIDEO_ENCODING_FFMPEG_PATH, '-i', input_file_path,
                '-i', logo_path, '-filter_complex','scale=1920:1080',
                'overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01)',
                '-codec:v', 'libx264','-crf', '18',
                '-preset', 'slow', '-b:v', '1000k', '-maxrate', '2000k', '-bufsize', '2000k',
                "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
                '-codec:a', 'aac', '-b:a', '128k', '-strict', '-2', output_file_path])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire filtergraph should be one argument.

`'-filter_complex','scale=1920:1080[main];[main][1]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-(main_w*0.01):y=main_h-overlay_h-(main_h*0.01)',`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the response, it works well now. Is `[main]` a keyword like variable or just a naming one? Could you also tell me how can I decrease the size of the logo image?
Thanks.

Comment: It's a linklabel. See last para at https://superuser.com/a/1172501/